# Recommended replacement for deprecated call_user_method?

Tags: php, deprecated

Since PHP's [`call_user_method()`](http://php.net/call_user_method) and [`call_user_method_array()`](http://php.net/manual/function.call-user-method-array.php) are marked deprecated I'm wondering what alternative is recommended?

One way would be to use [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/function.call-user-func.php), because by giving an array with an object and a method name as the first argument does the same like the deprecated functions. Since this function is not marked deprecated I assume the reason isn't the non-OOP-stylish usage of them?

The other way I can think of is using the [Reflection API](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.reflection.php), which might be the most comfortable and future-oriented alternative. Nevertheless it's more code and I could image that it's slower than using the functions mentioned above.

What I'm interested in:

- Is there a completely new technique for calling an object's methods by name?
- Which is the fastest/best/official replacement?
- What's the reason for deprecation?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As you said [`call_user_func`](http://www.php.net/call_user_func) can easily duplicate the behavior of this function. What's the problem?

The [`call_user_method`](http://us.php.net/call_user_method) page even lists it as the alternative:

```
<?php
call_user_func(array($obj, $method_name), $parameter /* , ... */);
call_user_func(array(&$obj, $method_name), $parameter /* , ... */); // PHP 4
?>
```

As far as to *why* this was deprecated, [this posting explains it:](http://www.mail-archive.com/php-dev@lists.php.net/msg11576.html)

> This is 
>   because the `call_user_method()` and `call_user_method_array()` functions 
>   can easily be duplicated by:
>
> old way:
>   `call_user_method($func, $obj, "method", "args", "go", "here");`
>
> new way:
>   `call_user_func(array(&$obj, "method"), "method", "args", "go", "here");`

Personally, I'd probably go with the variable variables suggestion posted by Chad.

Comment: It seems like the notice of deprecation in the PHP documentation on `call_user_method` should point you toward `call_user_func`.  Too bad it doesn't and I have to search SO for the answer...  =D

Answer (score 18):

You could do it using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), this looks the cleanest to me. Instead of:

```
call_user_func(array($obj, $method_name), $parameter);
```

You do:

```
$obj->{$method_name}($parameter);
```

Comment: The problem with that is when you have no idea which function will be called and if it does or not have parameter, how much parameters it has, etc. I'm using AMFPHP to communicate through Flex and PHP and I'm building a Gateway Caller that will prevent me to call PHP more than once from Flex per time. I'll need to instance and call more than one method and I have no idea if Flex will provide parameters and if it does, it will be in an given array.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like that :

I use something like that in my __construct() method.

```
$params = array('a','b','c'); // PUT YOUR PARAMS IN $params DYNAMICALLY

call_user_func_array(array($this, $this->_request), array($params));
```

1st argument : Obect instance, 
2nd argument : method to call, 
3rd argument : params

Before you can test if method or Class too, with :

```
method_exists()
class_exists()
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

if you get following error:
Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, second array member is not a valid method in C:\www\file.php on line X
and code like this:

```
call_user_func(array($this, $method));
```

use (string) declaration for $method name

```
call_user_func(array($this, (string)$method));
```