# The call_user_method_array function is deprecated what replaces it?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommended replacement for deprecated call_user_method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782846/recommended-replacement-for-deprecated-call-user-method)
>   [Function in PHP deprecated, what should I use now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151125/function-in-php-deprecated-what-should-i-use-now)

The `call_user_method_array` function is deprecated so what should I use to achieve the same outcome?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [manual](https://www.google.com/search?q=call_user_method_array&oq=call_user_method_array&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

> Example #1 `call_user_method_array()` alternative

```
 <?php
 call_user_func_array(array($obj, $method_name), $params);
 call_user_func_array(array(&$obj, $method_name), $params); // PHP 4
 ?>
```

Comment: some how missed that on the page. I was looking at the warning and was expecting them to list a replacement function.

Answer (score 2):

The call_user_method_array() function is deprecated as of PHP 4.1.0.

Now You can use the **call_user_func_array** (callable $callback, array $parameters), where $callback or string function name or an array ( $object, $function_name ).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php